# Override instance variable of parent controller in child controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three controllers that all inherit from `ApplicationController`.
The child controllers are:

`HomeController`

- `index`

The home controller has only one method, `index`, and it only renders a form.

`TemplatesController`

- `templates`
- `save_page_name`
- `preview`

The `TemplatesController` has three methods. `templates` lists all the templates and `preview` opens a preview of the selected template. `save_page_name` is the endpoint of a form submitted from `home#index`.

`DesignsController`

- `home`
- `about`

`template#preview` renders a view with an `iframe` which contains `design#home`.

Every method in `DesignsController` requires the value set from the form to fetch the data from. (Data is being fetched from an API.)

Now. I want to create a globally accessible variable for the `DesignController`. I.e. I want to make the value come from the form global. So I have put some code in parent controller

**Here is my code:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :page_name

  def page_name
    @page_name = ''
  end
end
```

and intend on overriding it in `template#save_page_name`:

```
def save_page_name
  @page_name = params[:page_name]
  test_page_name = PageName.new
  test_page_name.name = @page_name

  if test_page_name.save
    redirect_to(controller: 'template', action: 'templates')
  end
end
```

This is the form

```
<%= form_tag({controller: 'application', action: "save_page_name"}, class: "nifty_form") do%>
<%= text_field_tag :page_name %>
```

This is the template controller

```
class TemplateController < ApplicationController
  def templates
  end

  def preview
  end
end
```

Design controller

```
class DesignController < ApplicationController
  def home
  @info = @page_name //should be global var
  render :template => "design/"+params[:template]+"/home"
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @spickermann, first of all sorry for my englis
I am trying to override the instance variable of parent class from the child class.

Comment: And what problem do you have? Is there an error?

Comment: no, there is no error but I can not seem to update the instance variable from the child class.
I had also post another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918592/globally-accessible-variable-in-rails/32920506#32920506

Comment: Please post the code for the form as well. Controller action and template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the way you define your `page_name` method in the application controller to:

```
def page_name
  @page_name ||= ''
end
```

The method `page_name` will by default, set @page_name to an empty string, but will also allow you to assign a different value, via `page_name = "something_else"`

And - `@page_name` is not a global variable. It is an instance variable of the controller class. When your app calls the controller, an instance of the controller class is used, and this instance variable will be available within the context of the controller instance.